# jQuery or markup?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've successfully gotten my menu to be sticky using jQuery waypoints in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/decade/uYBYM/). It works fine in the fiddle, but when I implement on my [test drupal site](http://drupal.scienceworld.ca), it's no longer active.

Here's the markup:

```
<?php if ($page['main_menu']): ?>
  <div id="stickywrapper">
    <div class="main-menu-wrapper">
      <div class="main-menu-wrapper-inner <?php echo $grid_size ?>">
        <nav id="main-menu" class="<?php echo $grid_full_width ?> clearfix">
          <?php print render($page['search_box']); ?>
          <?php print render($page['main_menu']); ?>
        </nav>
      </div><!--end main-menu-wrapper-inner-->
    </div><!--end main-menu-wrapper-->
  </div><!--end stickywrapper-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a stray Unicode zero width space (U+200B) character at the end of the JavaScript code in `stickymenu.js`, causing a syntax error. Delete that and it all works out.